# Faster alternatives to mpmath in Python for computations?

Tags: python, numpy, calculation, mpmath

I am doing calculations with Python that involve using the sinh function element-wise on a couple 2D Numpy arrays.

Because I got overflow errors with the sinh implementation of NumPy on a couple arrays, I switched to the mpmath implementation for parts of the calculations that unfortunately does not support vectorisation, so I have to iterate over each array element, which I think makes the calculation much slower than before, because the parts that still use NumPy are much faster while still "effectively" doing the same amount of calculations (few minutes with NumPy vs hours with mpmath).

I am currently using the following loop to apply the mpmath sinh function element-wise on the 2D numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
import mpmath as mp

y1=np.linspace(0,h,250,False) 
y2=np.linspace(h,b,800)
y=np.concatenate((y1,y2))

chi_1n=np.arange(1,N+1)*np.pi/(a)
y_zone1=np.reshape(y[y<=h],(1,-1))
chi1_y1=chi_n1*y_zone1

A1=chi_1n_t*h_vector1
sinhZ1=np.empty(A1.shape,dtype=object)
    for i in range(0,A1.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0,A1.shape[1]):
            sinhZ1[i,j]=mp.sinh(A1[i,j])
```

a,b and h are just some float variables.

Now with NumPy, I could just dump the 2D matrix into the function and it would return a value much faster than `mp.sinh`, albeit with an overflow.

```
sinhZ1=np.sinh(A1)
```

Is there a way to make the calculations quicker? I thought there may be a Python library that supports vectorisation for its sinh function AND very large numbers.

Making the arguments artifically smaller by capping them would be not ideal, because the array is used as a basis for a series.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Numpy is not designed to be fast for Python objects, but for native objects. It is also not designed to be fast for direct access to items. In general, operation needs to be vectorized and operate on native types. For objects, list are often as fast as Numpy array or even faster. CPython object are inherently slow because of the CPython interpreter itself. Loops are also slow for the same reason. If you need fast loop in such a case, then Python is not the good language.

Comment: Assuming the bottleneck is neither Numpy nor CPython but `mpmath` (unlikely), then you can try another library like GMP (known to be fast, especially for very-precise numbers). Note that GMP is also available in native languages like C/C++ (which provides fast loops and fast array access).

Comment: I'm more curious about the overflow; what input values cause an overflow for NumPy sinh? Do you really need such large (output) values?

Comment: So a quick test shows that `np.sinh(800)` produces `np.inf` and the warning (which can be surpressed), while `mpmath(sinh(800` gives `mpf('1.3631872860562832e+347')`.  I think float64 limit is something like `e308`.  Look at your larger calculation context to see whether you really need to work with values this big.  Maybe the `inf` value is just as useful.

Comment: What do you do with these values after this? Using logarithm identities and the log-sum-exp trick, you can effectively calculate `log(sinh(x))` without computing `sinh(x)` first, avoiding overflow. Depending on what you need to do with the values, you might continue to work in log-space, or maybe there is some other part of the calculation that brings the magnitudes back down, after which you can exponentiate.

Comment: BTW, rather than the double `for` loop, consider defining `mpsinh = np.vectorize(mp.sinh)`, then you can do `sinhZ1 = mpsinh(A1)`. It is unlikely to be much faster, but it keeps the code cleaner.
Also, if you think the `log(sinh(x))` idea is relevant, I can write it up as an answer. I clocked it at about 40x faster on my machine, but of course it depends on what you need to do with the values.

Comment: @9769953 I need to compute a dozen coefficients of a series (for a electrostatics problem, if you are more curious) and I would like to take more coefficients into consideration to see how the computed potential changes.

Comment: @hpaulj It would be not ideal, because I am calculating the coefficients of a series and I would like to see how the amount of coefficients changes the result (it is an electrostatics problem whose solution with the series seems odd at places)

Comment: @JérômeRichard Honestly, I used NumPy mostly for convenience, as it has neat built-in functions that are useful for me purposes, but especially because I have already written out the code when I noticed the slow run time. I will give Python lists and the GMP library a try. Thanks!

Comment: @MattHaberland I considered the log idea, but because I thought the idea would still require computing the actual sinh, I did not implement it. How can I exploit the "log-sum-exp trick" (idk what it is) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comments, you can compute the log of the `sinh` function without overflow like:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import logsumexp

def logsinh(x):
    ones = np.ones_like(x)
    return logsumexp([x, -x], b=[ones, -ones], axis=0) - np.log(2)
```

The [log-sum-exp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp) trick implemented by [`scipy.special.logsumexp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.logsumexp.html) computes the log of the sum of exponentials while avoiding over/underflow. The first argument is just the log of the terms in the numerator of `sinh`, the parameter `b` is a scaling factor that lets us do subtraction instead of addition, and `-np.log(2)` is the equivalent of division by `2` within the log function.

Comparing performance against `mpmath.sinh`:

```
from mpmath import mp
mp.dps = 16

rng = np.random.default_rng()
x = rng.random(size=(100000))*10000

mpsinh = np.vectorize(mp.sinh)
mplog = np.vectorize(mp.log)

%timeit logsinh(x) # 13.1 ms ± 1.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit mpsinh(x)  # 1.16 s ± 287 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

np.testing.assert_allclose(logsinh(x), mplog(mpsinh(x)).astype(np.float64), rtol=5e-15)
```

If you need to work with negative `x`, you'll have to use complex dtype. `log(-x)` has the same real part of `log(x)` but has imaginary part `pi`.

```
np.testing.assert_allclose(logsinh(-x + 0j), logsinh(x) + np.pi*1j)
```